# Ruby - memory game

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am trying to build a very simple game using Ruby that will be on the web. I am am trying to:

user goes to page and a string appears for X amount of seconds and then after X amount hide it and ask for the user input then check to see how far the person got (how many they guessed right)

I would have strings for:

timeout in seconds text string user input string

Then I am not sure how to compare both strings.

Comment: If this question is directly related to ruby, why is it only tagged as dhtml?  I just want to make sure I am understanding the question.

Comment: Wrong tag, just changed them up.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions as to the algorithms you can use:

- [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to measure how correct the user's input were to the originals.
- Look at [Fuzzy string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_string_searching) as well if you are really brave.
- Depending on the language of the strings, it may be fun to hack up a [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) based matcher.

Comment: Went WAY over my head, is there any other approach to this or any other game you can think of? Something to get my hands on and get some experience coding. I already did a guess a number game. Ryan

Comment: To start off, try a naive string comparison. If your original text was "apple", the user has to enter "apple" to get any points. Next, take a step further by giving him some points, hints about what part he got right etc.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you start with strings, but handle the data in arrays. (Includes the string to array method.)  You can use this for anything that can fit in an array.  simply call with two strings and get the score back.  This works just as well when either string is shorter.

```
#string to char array
def s_to_a(s)
  a = [] 
  s.each_char{|c| a << c}
  a
end

def memory_rating(s1, s2)
  score = 0

  #convert both strings to arrays
  a1 = s_to_a(s1)
  a2 = s_to_a(s2)

  a1.each do |e|
    # shift allows easy access to all elements of a2 
    # inside the iterator for a1
    score += (e == a2.shift) ? 1 : 0
  end
  score
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simplistic approach just off top of my head, you can treat it as an char array comparison instead of a string comparison.

Let's say the string "abcdefg" was shown and user typed in "abdcefg", he is considered to remember 5 out of 7 of the given string.